# Adding menu to scene in Cocos2d causes scene to render as black screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm getting some odd behavior out of Cocos2d when I load a scene and add a menu.

From another scene, I use replaceScene to enter this one. Normally, it renders fine. However, if I add the following code to the init method, the whole screen renders blank after the replaceScene is called! The framerate is still visible and changing, so the engine hasn't locked up. The menu and the screen's previous contents are simply not shown. Some of these contents come from an overridden draw() method; those also do not show after the menu code below is added.

```
CCMenuItemFont *item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString: @"Clear" target:self selector:@selector(clearSelections:)];
CCMenuItemFont *item2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString: @"Blank" target:self selector:@selector(performBlankSelection:)];
CCMenuItemFont *item3 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString: @"Enter" target:self selector:@selector(submitSelections:)];
CCMenu * taskMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1, item2, item3, nil];
[taskMenu alignItemsHorizontally];
[taskMenu setPosition:ccp(size.width/2, size.height/4)];
[self addChild:taskMenu];
```

I'm not really sure where to begin to solve resolve this issue.

Comment: This certainly isn't anything i've experienced in cocos2d, you mention an overridden draw() method. And your problem is to do with drawing when the contents are called in. I imagine your problem lies there. Can we see this overridden method?

Also, at any point do you get any memory warnings? It's possible some assets are getting deallocated because of a memory warning and when called in again, have been cleared from the cache?

Comment: @Bongeh
No memory warnings.I also have some labels which render correctly if the menu code is absent. The draw() code, which executes and renders correctly if the menu code is absent, follows:

-(void) draw
{
    //draw squares for each of the cells in the grid
    for (int i=0; i<grid_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<grid_size; j++)
        {
            s_x = o_x+(i*s)+grid_x_offset;
            s_y = o_y+(j*s)+grid_y_offset;
            CGPoint vertices[] = { ccp(s_x,s_y), ccp(s_x+s,s_y), ccp(s_x+s,s_y+s), ccp(s_x,s_y+s) };
            ccDrawPoly(vertices, 4, YES);
        }
    }
}